# Did the community delete a bunch of old questions?

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-questions

I was just curious about my stats and realized that some 25% of my accepted answers are not there anymore, while my reputation did not change.

So my (simple) question is:

Has there been a major Cleanup in the last few days?

And as a (quite obvious) followup, the reputation awarded for an answer that is later deleted sticks to the user forever, or am I wrong here?

Greetings from snowy Austria :)

Comment: Greetings back from grey Vienna :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there was no major clean-up. Of your five deleted answers …

- two were deleted by yourself ([this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75576/which-set-of-plugins-do-you-use-most-for-your-projects/75577#75577) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52178/highlight-parent-menu-item-when-child-is-not-in-menu/52180#52180)),
- [one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51101/update-option-creates-the-option-in-the-database-but-doesnt-insert-the-value/51106#51106) was deleted when the asker deleted the question, and
- two were deleted by me. [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77539/adding-meta-box-to-custom-post-type/77541#77541) was really just a comment, and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33994/get-post-count-for-a-category-term/50645#50645) was a bare link to the duplicate.

Comment: Okay, no Problem, just wanted to be sure about it. The reputation of deleted Stuff sticks, right?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. When a post with +3 is deleted you lose 30 points. That’s why you should not answer poor question: we clean those up from time, and it hurts more to lose something. :)